# Bitbucket project URL replicated when using jenkins pipelines when using 'pipeline script from SCM'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can't help thinking there is a much better way to do a git clone in a pipeline without explicitly mention the repo and branch names? To be more precise the pipeline is already defined in a repo and accessed via a "pipeline script from SCM" step.

```
node('myrole') {
    stage('my dupplication') {
        echo " jenkins pipeline "       git url: 'ssh://xyz/myproject/myprojectrepoa.git', branch : 'featureX' 

    } }
```

how can I tell my pipeline to do something like : `git url $currentRepo, branch : $myfeature` instead of repeating the repo info (and possibly avoid confusions & issues if inadvertently the two are not in sync anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Found that while using multibranch pipeline (or pipeline with scm) the below command will check out the current branch and avoid having the project url duplicated:

```
checkout scm
```

seen in https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multibranch-projects

Comment: more info in https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch-